# Решить пример и вывести результат

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Дан такой пример
4-(4+4)/4+1
Я написал вот такое решение

```
DATA SEGMENT
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
        ASSUME cs:code, ds:DATA
start:
    mov ax,4
    mov bx,4
    add ax,bx
    div bx
    mov bx,4
    sub bx,ax
    mov ax,1
    add ax,bx
    mov ax,4C00h
    int 21h
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Как вывести результат находящийся в AX на экран?

Comment: Сначала решите в какой системе счисления выводить и укажите это в вопросе. http://asmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/022-vyvod-chisel-na-konsol/